# ResultSet implementation - is it fetched as next() is called, or the results are already in memory?

Tags: java

Assuming that I have to go through all the entries., does anyone know how the results for ResultSet is fetched?

Can I call `SELECT * FROM MyTable` instead of `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 0;` and just call `resultSet.next()` as needed to fetch the results, and process them on a program level, or are the results already in memory and not putting in `TOP` is bad?

Comment: A result set is using a database cursor, see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: Do you need other clarifications or the answers are complete? I can edit if you feel like it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResultSet` class exposes a

```
void setFetchSize(int rows)
```

method, which, per *JavaDoc*

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be
>   fetched from the database when more rows are needed for this `ResultSet`
>   object.

That means if we have a result set of `200` rows from the database, and we set the fetch size to `100`, `~100` rows will loaded from the database at a time, and two trips to the database might be required.

The default fetch size is driver dependant, but for example, `Oracle` set it to `10` rows.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the DB engine and JDBC driver. Generally, the *IDEA* behind the JDBC API is that the DB engine creates a cursor (this is also why ResultSets are resources that must be closed), and thus, you can do a `SELECT * FROM someTableWithBillionsOfRows` without a `LIMIT`, and yet it can be fast.

Whether it actually is, well, that depends. In my experience, which is primarily interacting with postgres, it *IS* fast (as in, cursor based with limited data transfer from DB to VM even if the query would match billions of rows), and thus your plan (select without limits, keep calling next until you have what you want and then close the resultset) should work fine.

NB: Some DB engines meet you halfway and transfer results in batches, for the best of both worlds: Latency overhead is limited (a single latency overhead is shared by *batchsize* results), and yet the total transfer between DB and VM is limited to only *rowsize times batchsize*, even if you only read a single row and then close the resultset.